# how to update all the input form data based from session in one hit submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this shopping cart page, wherein, it displays the products + price and their quantities
now my problem is, I dunno how to make the total number of items and price updated, once I input  a different number of quantity and hit update button

here's my function that "lists" the products based from the $_SESSION data

```
public function getCartListings(){
 if (is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty){
      $query = "SELECT * FROM gg_t_wsproducts WHERE ProductID = $id";
      $result = mysql_query($query);
      if (!$result){
        echo "Couldn't execute query: ".mysql_error();
        exit;
      }
      $product = $this->getProduct($id);

        echo '<div class="cart-content">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="20%" align="center" style="vertical-align:top !important;">
                                <img src="images/shopping-cart/thumb-image.png" />
                            </td>
                            <td width="80%" style="vertical-align:top !important;">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-bottom:2px solid #c6c6c6; padding-bottom:10px">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="60%"><b style="font-size:18px">'.$product["ProductName"].'</b></td>
                                            <td width="20%">Qty &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="proditem"  name="'.$id.'" type="text" style="width:20px; margin:0 0 0 4px;" value="'.$qty.'"></td>
                                            <td width="20%"><span style="font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;">$'.number_format($product['ProductOverridePrice'],2).'</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="50%" valign="bottom" align="left"><br>
                                                <span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;">$'.number_format($product['ProductOverridePrice'],2).'</span><br>
                                                <img src="images/shopping-cart/star.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/shopping-cart/star.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/shopping-cart/star.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/shopping-cart/star.png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="images/shopping-cart/star.png" /><br>
                                                <span style="font-size:12px; color:#828282;">14 reviews</span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="50%" valign="bottom" align="right">
                                                <a class="removefromcart" name="'.$id.'" id="'.$qty.'" href="#"><img src="images/shopping-cart/remove-item-btn.png" border="0" /></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>';

    }//end foreach
  }

}
```

As you can see above, the items are coming from the foreach loop

here's the front-end code that display the actual items

```
    <div id="catalog-wrapper">
        <form action="#" method="POST" id="updatecart">
        <h1 class="cart-header">ITEMS IN YOUR CART <span style="float:right"><a href="#"><input type="image" name="updatecart" src="images/shopping-cart/update-cart-btn.png" border="0" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="catalog.php"><img style="float:right;" src="images/shopping-cart/continue-shopping-btn.png" border="0" /></a></span></h1>
        <?php $myCart->getCartListings(); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and now, here's the "useless" jquery code i have

```
   $('input[name="updatecart"]').click(function(){
      var pid = $('input#proditem').attr('id');
      var qty2 = $('input[type="text"]').each(function(idx,elem){
       });
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "classes/ajax.cartupdate.php",
        data: "pid="+pid+"&qty2="+qty2,
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
          location.reload();
        }
      });
      return false;
   });
```

the ajax PHP code should have been something like this...but am still having a problem with those codes above..not really sure what to do

```
if ($qty2){
  $cart->updateCart($qty2);
  $_SESSION['total_items'] = $cart->totalItems($_SESSION['cart']);
  $_SESSION['total_price'] = $cart->totalPrice($_SESSION['cart']);
  echo "cartUpdated!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are getting multiple variables? Just get one array and explode it on server side with PHP. I mean, create a javascript array and include every input value in it and then send it to PHP. But in your code there will be two array, no problem. It would like this:

```
pid="1,2,3,4,5,6,7"+&qtty="0,1,1,0,1,1,0"
```

Get this values with PHP and explode them to "," and do whatever you want with for loop. By the way, if you will reload the page after sending, then why you are using the ajax method?

Comment: are you suggesting, that I should use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] to submit the same page ?